# WinForms Editor: How to display a child object as a nested object in the Designer

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to display a WinForms control with child objects to display the child objects as editable nodes in the editor. I'm thinking it should work similar to the way that the Font editor works in the Window form/control designer.

[image]

In a nutshell the scenario is this:

```cs
public MyEditorControl : UserControl 
{
     // get this property to display as an expandable object?
     public EditorConfiguration Configuration {get; set; }
}
```

It looks like `TypeConverter` and `UITypeEditor` are involved but I can't find any examples on how an object should be handled using these type implementations.

Comment: Wow, memories... That was a long time ago... This might help some... https://stackoverflow.com/q/3568341/1048799

Comment: [ExpandableObjectConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter). Decoarate the *expandable* class with `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]`. Your class needs to provide a constructor for the `EditorConfiguration` class. It can be just `public EditorConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = new EditorConfiguration();`.

Comment: This of course provides the default editors for the different types of the `EditorConfiguration` properties, so you may want to assign default values to all properties. If you instead need a custom type converter for one or more properties, you need to build a class that derives from `ExpandableObjectConverter` and override `ConvertFrom`, `ConvertTo` (`CreateInstance`, eventually) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need, as you mentioned, a [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8), and override the following methods (see the attached link for details):

```
// Override the two methods below when you need new instance per user edit
public override bool GetCreateInstanceSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return true;
}

public override object CreateInstance(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
    IDictionary propertyValues)
{
    return new EditorConfiguration
    {
        Value1 = (string) propertyValues["Value1"],
        Value2 = (string) propertyValues["Value2"]
    };
}

// You get the two methods below if inherit from ExpandableObjectConverter
// If you need extra logic such as property name ordering, you still need to
// override the correct methods to do so
public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return true;
}

public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(
    ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value,
    Attribute[] attributes)
{
    return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(EditorConfiguration), attributes);
}
```

And use the type converter:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EditorConfigurationConverter))]
public class EditorConfiguration
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in designer, you could see:
[image]

If all properties could be configured via the Designer, you might not need a custom [`UITypeEditor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor?view=netframework-4.8).

You need a `UITypeEditor` only when you want to provide alternative / advanced experience to set the configuration. For example, if you want to read configuration from a file, then you could implement `UITypeEditor` to be able to select the file using a "Open file" dialog / file selector.

Comment: Yes that worked for me. Actually I had this set up but for some reason it didn't initially work because - I didn't initialize the type so it was null and not showing in the editor.

Also related obstacle. The type converter messes with JSON Serialization which produces the `ToString()` output rather than a properly serialized structure.